# iPython matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I try to import submodule pyplot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I get following error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-21-eff513f636fd> in <module>()
----> 1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in <module>()
     27 from cycler import cycler
     28 import matplotlib
---> 29 import matplotlib.colorbar
     30 from matplotlib import style
     31 from matplotlib import _pylab_helpers, interactive

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py in <module>()
     32 import matplotlib.artist as martist
     33 import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
---> 34 import matplotlib.collections as collections
     35 import matplotlib.colors as colors
     36 import matplotlib.contour as contour

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py in <module>()
     25 import matplotlib.artist as artist
     26 from matplotlib.artist import allow_rasterization
---> 27 import matplotlib.backend_bases as backend_bases
     28 import matplotlib.path as mpath
     29 from matplotlib import _path

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py in <module>()
     60 
     61 import matplotlib.tight_bbox as tight_bbox
---> 62 import matplotlib.textpath as textpath
     63 from matplotlib.path import Path
     64 from matplotlib.cbook import mplDeprecation, warn_deprecated

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\textpath.py in <module>()
     16 from matplotlib.ft2font import FT2Font, KERNING_DEFAULT, LOAD_NO_HINTING
     17 from matplotlib.ft2font import LOAD_TARGET_LIGHT
---> 18 from matplotlib.mathtext import MathTextParser
     19 import matplotlib.dviread as dviread
     20 from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mathtext.py in <module>()
     58 
     59 import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
---> 60 import matplotlib._png as _png
     61 ####################
     62 

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Matplotlib is installed. Any ideas?

Comment: I get the same with the newest Anaconda packages :( For whatever reason the `Lib/site-packages` it still shows the `matplotlib-1.4.3.egg.info` file despite me having a newer matplotlib installed.

Comment: I believe I had some success deleting `Lib/site-packages/_pycache`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not in your python search path for modules.

See section 6.1.2 in the tutorial on modules: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Basically, you need to add the directory where the dll is installed to the library search path.

Comment: I created PythonPath system variable and added all paths (libs, dlls, etc) but error is the same

Comment: Did you check sys.path and verify that it contains the correct directory? There could be a bunch of problems. It could be that the pythonpath sys variable isn't picked up, or that the directory path is incorrect, or pointing at the wrong directory. Did you restart your development environment after setting the path system variable?

Comment: When I start anaconda cmd, it reports c:\Anaconda3 and c:\Anaconda3\Scripts are added to the path. Yes I restarted the development env, but still have the same error.

Comment: Also checked sys.path (imported sys, and printed all) and all the paths are there.